# How to calculate Lebesgue integral on a difference of balls?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

How to calculate Lebesgue integral on a difference of balls?

Such as:

$\int_{B(0,2) \setminus {\overline{B}(0,1)}}$

Answer (score 1):

$\overline{B}(0,1)\subset B(0,2)$ thus
$$ \int_{B(0,2)\setminus\overline{B}(0,1)}d\mu=\int_{B(0,2)}d\mu-\int_{\overline{B}(0,1)}d\mu $$

Comment: Good. What if the latter integral happens to be $\infty$?

Comment: The Lebesgue integral of a ball cannot be $+\infty$.

Comment: Consider $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\overline{B}(0,1)} \log(1+\frac{1}{|x|^i})$? The inside is infinity.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were considering $\int_{B}1d\mu$. In this case the previous identity is true only if the two integrals on the right side are finite.